# Infura getFilterLogs api returns empty array

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, infura, logs, filters

I am trying to filter transfer events using node.js for a contract address between a range of blocks. I am trying to filter the latest 7 transactions which can be shown in etherscan [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x683f6e80c378e57fea188d53f4440600e87abc46#tokentxnsErc721). My code is as follows:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

let infura_url = "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/853346f695b740fe8bd7d8f583bcf55f"
let web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(infura_url))

let fromBlock = web3.utils.toHex(10394853);
let toBlock = web3.utils.toHex(10399444);
let address = "0x683f6e80c378e57fea188d53f4440600e87abc46";
let blockHash = "0xb3b20624f8f0f86eb50dd04688409e5cea4bd02d700bf6e79e9384d47d6a5a35"
let topic = ["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"];

let body = {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "eth_getLogs",
    "params": [{
        "toBlock": fromBlock,
        "fromBlock": toBlock,
        "address": address,
        //"blockHash" : blockHash
        "topic": topic
    }],
    "id": 1
};

fetch(infura_url, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
}).then(result => result.json())
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(err => res.json({ error: err.message }));
```

However it returns an empty array as result:

```
{ jsonrpc: '2.0', id: 1, result: [] }
```

Also, I want to understand how to pass the fromBlock and toBlock. The documentation says that the blockFrom can be an integer number but when I write it in integer it says the value should be hex  "0x". No address is working in the address filter. The only results I can get are with blockHAsh. Kindly help me in figuring out the issue. The contract address, toBlock, fromBlock and topic is mentioned in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where exactly your problem is, but you can do the whole thing directly with web3 (instead of an HTTP request):

```
const params = {
    address  : "0x683f6e80c378e57fea188d53f4440600e87abc46",
    topics   : ["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"],
    fromBlock: 10394853,
    toBlock  : 10399444
};
web3.eth.getPastLogs(params).then(response => ...
```

---

**Update - I also know where your problem is:**

You are using the address of one of the parties involved in the transfer events (i.e., the `from` in some cases and the `to` in other cases), while you should be using the address of the specific token involved, as you can see [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xcfbdfae43774c3aec9911f7826380fac9f88c82ef4b038d834bca8b9cfac004c#eventlog) for example:

- Address 0xdceaf1652a131f32a821468dc03a92df0edd86ea
- Address 0x67cbbb366a51fff9ad869d027e496ba49f5f6d55

Comment: Thankyou so much your comment solved my problem. It is now returning logs.